# Audio captions with HTML5 <audio> element

Tags: html, audio, html5-video, html5-audio, webvtt

I would like to have the transcription of an audio file to be shown as the audio plays. I've tried several options to no avail:

`<audio src="../audio/myaudio.mp3" controls>
<track default srclang="en" kind="captions" label="English subtitles" src="sub.vtt"/>
</audio>`

The path to the .vtt file is correct. The `<track>` element is supposed to be child of both `<video>` and `<audio>` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track). Why can't I display my captions?

My .vtt file contains something like

```
WEBVTT FILE

1
00:00:03.500 --> 00:00:05.000
D:vertical A:start First line

2
00:00:06.000 --> 00:00:09.000
A:start second line
```

etc...

I've also tried by using the `<video>` element:

```
<video style="background: black; width:360px; height:260px;" src="../audio/mayaudio.mp3" controls>
<track default srclang="en" kind="subtitles" label="English subtitles" src="sub.vtt"/>
</video>
```

Still no luck. I can see the 'CC' button and I can also select the Elnglish subtitles item. The audio plays (even if I use the `<video>` element) and I can't see any caption. Swapping 'captions' with 'subtitles' doesn't help.

Comment: The line number, timecodes, and dialogue should all be on separate lines. That might help, at least with the `<video>` case

Comment: Yes - it's just how it is displayed in my question box, in my file they're separate lines. I'll avoid my question just to avoid confusion, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I gave up at the time. I don't know if there have been more recent developments / fixes.